# Matrix splitting and multiplication in python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix-multiplication

I have this 2 matrix: first `[P,1]` and second `[N*P,2]`, in Python.

I want to multiplicate the first for the `[P,2]` submatrix of the second, N-times (without for cycles).

I'll give you an example:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
```

So, in this case, `P=3 N=2`. The result should be a matrix `[N,2]`. In the example:

```
res=[[22,28],[58,64]]
```

I've tried with `reshape(P,N*2)`, but I don't it can be worth.
Suggestions?

Comment: When I saied "multiplicate" means "scalar product" (np.dot), for the first matrix to every N submatrix of the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the orders you have, what you want is

```
np.sum(a[None,:,None]*b.reshape(2,3,2), axis=1)
```

You need to retranspose your data in an intermediate space because they are not interleaved as we expect.

Comment: What's for that "axes=(2,0, 1)"?

Comment: This is to transpose `b` as you need, swapping the last two axes. The shape of `b` is `2,3,2`, and you need to have 3 as the last element in the shape to the multiplication. Actually, let me try something else.

Comment: @GiorgioCesaritti  no need for the transpose, just change the shape of a, b as you need, multiply and sum ;)

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work. Have you seen my last comment about "scalar product"? Maybe it can be worth...

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? If I use your a, b, I get the result you specified. And yes, I understood, that's why there is a sum over products on the axes where we want your dot product. Due to broadcasting, we cannot use tensordot.

Answer (score 0):

A way with each sub-matrix calculated in a list comprehension and a final vertical stack

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
b = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])
c = numpy.vstack([numpy.dot(a, b[x * a.shape[0]:(x + 1) * a.shape[0], :])
                  for x in range(int(b.shape[0] / a.shape[0]))])
print(c)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't use for cycles

Comment: Even though the for loop here is not used for the matrix multiplication ?

Comment: I can't use for cycles allover the project